# Rocket Chip - Access Exception on Page Table Walk

Tags: chisel, page-tables, rocket-chip

I am trying to integrate a RoCC accelerator with RocketChip / Chipyard. Given a virtual address, the accelerator should translate it to a physical address, read some data from memory and then start a black box accelerator (e.g. AES).
I looked at some examples and (so far) mostly followed the TranslatorExample included in RocketChip. However, the PTW request throws an access exception (`ptw.resp.bits.ae_ptw` is set). What am I missing?

This is my RoCC code:

```
class AESAcceleratorModule(outer: MyAESAccelerator)(implicit p: Parameters)
    extends LazyRoCCModuleImp(outer) with HasCoreParameters {

    val busy = RegInit(Bool(false))

    val req_rd = Reg(Bits(width = 5))
    val funct = io.cmd.bits.inst.funct
    val loadKey = funct === UInt(0)
    val loadPlain = funct === UInt(1)

    
    // Memory Stuff
    val pte = Reg(new PTE)
    val input_addr = Reg(UInt(coreMaxAddrBits.W))
    val input_offset = input_addr(pgIdxBits - 1, 0)
    val input_vpn = input_addr(coreMaxAddrBits - 1, pgIdxBits)
    val input = Reg(UInt(64))

    // State Handling
    object CtrlState extends ChiselEnum {
        val sIdle, sLoadKey, sPTWalk, sPTResp, sResp = Value
    }
    val cstate = RegInit(CtrlState.sIdle)

    // Default Signal Assign:
    io.cmd.ready := (cstate === CtrlState.sIdle)
    io.busy := (cstate =/= CtrlState.sIdle)
    io.resp.valid := (cstate === CtrlState.sResp || cstate === CtrlState.sLoadKey)
    io.resp.bits.rd := req_rd
    io.resp.bits.data := 1.U

    // Translate Address
    when(io.cmd.fire && loadPlain){
        input_addr := io.cmd.bits.rs1
        printf("Input Address: %x\n", io.cmd.bits.rs1)
        cstate := CtrlState.sPTWalk
    }

    private val ptw = io.ptw(0)

    ptw.req.valid := (cstate === CtrlState.sPTWalk)
    ptw.req.bits.valid := true.B
    ptw.req.bits.bits.addr := input_vpn
    
    when (ptw.req.fire()) { cstate := CtrlState.sPTResp }

    when (cstate === CtrlState.sPTResp && ptw.resp.valid) {
        printf("Got PT Response:\n")
        pte := ptw.resp.bits.pte
        cstate := CtrlState.sResp
        when(ptw.resp.bits.ae_ptw){
            printf("Access Exception") // <-- This happens
        }
        when(ptw.resp.bits.pf){
            printf("Page Fault")
        }
    }

    // Data is 0xFFFF...FF - presumably due to the access exception
    io.resp.bits.data := Mux(pte.leaf(), Cat(pte.ppn, input_offset), -1.S(xLen.W).asUInt)
    when (cstate === CtrlState.sResp && io.resp.fire){
        input := Mux(pte.leaf(), Cat(pte.ppn, input_offset), -1.S(xLen.W).asUInt)
        cstate := CtrlState.sIdle 
    }
    
    // Be busy when have pending memory requests or committed possibility of pending requests
    io.interrupt := Bool(false)
    
    // Set this true to trigger an interrupt on the processor (please refer to supervisor documentation)
    io.mem.req.valid := Bool(false)

}
```

And the config file:

```
class MyAESAcceleratorConfig extends Config(
  new WithMyAESAccelerator ++
  new RocketConfig)

class WithMyAESAccelerator extends Config ((site, here, up) => {
  case BuildRoCC => up(BuildRoCC) ++ Seq(
    (p: Parameters) => {
      val aes = LazyModule.apply(new MyAESAccelerator(OpcodeSet.custom2)(p))
      aes
    }
  )
})
```

This is the C code I am executing which does not return the desired result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "../../tests/rocc.h"

int main(void)
{
    uint64_t result = 0;
    
    uint64_t myint =   0xAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA;
    printf("%lx\n", &myint);
    asm volatile("fence");
    ROCC_INSTRUCTION_DSS(2, result, &myint, 0, 1);
    printf("The result of func1 was %lx\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you haven't figured this out, I assume you are running baremetal C tests. In baremetal VM is not used. This can be found out by checking the `ptbr.mode` signal (see RISC-V privileged spec section 4).
If you want to test PTW, you can run spike or VCS/verilator with proxy kernel.

Comment: Thanks! I did find another way but it's good to know what was the issue there.